# Format date returned from UIDatePicker

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter, uidatepicker

I have a `UIDatePicker` that is set to just pick a date (no time). I want to take the value that the user selects and reformat it. The value I get back includes the date, time, and timezone.

I have a `NSDateFormatter` ready with the locale and format I want set. The problem is when I try to format the date, the method call from the formatter returns nil:

```
NSDate *pickedDate = self.datePicker.date;
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setLocale: [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier: @"en_US"]];
[formatter setDateFormat: @"MM/dd"];

NSString *formattedDate = [formatter stringFromDate: pickedDate]; // nil
```

It looks as if the value returned from `self.datePicker.date` has already been formatted as a string. I've read that `NSDates` don't include the timezone. But, Apple's documentation very clearly says that the `date` property of `UIDatePicker` returns a `NSDate`.

I've also done some logging to see exactly what type is being returned, and I found that there is a subtle difference:

```
NSLog("%@", [self.datePicker.date class]); // logs "__NSDate"
NSLog("%@", [NSDate class]); // logs "NSDate"
```

Has anyone come across this, and if so what have you done to format the `NSDate`? I'm trying to format the date as `MM/dd` to use as a key in a `NSDictionary` object, and I only need the month and date, the year and time is not important.

Comment: No, the value returned from the picker is not formatted as a string, it's an NSDate object -- if you log it, you will see a string because what's logged is the string returned by NSDate's description method. Did you log pickedDate to make sure it's not nil? Is the line "NSString *formattedDate = …" in the same method as where you instantiate your formatter?

Comment: The code looks correct.  Unless `pickedDate` is nil I would expect this to return something.  You could try setting the `dateStyle` to one of the standard ones and maybe pass in a known good `NSDate` object like `[NSDate date]`.

Comment: @rdelmar, i have logged pickedDate and it is not nil. I've actually created my own DateFormatter class, as I format all the dates used in my app the same way. Rather than repeat the same few lines over and over again, I figured this would help. I currently have it set up as a property on my class and instantiate a new instance in the property's getter

Comment: I copied your code, replacing the picker date with [NSDate date], and it worked fine. I'll repeat my question -  Is the line "NSString *formattedDate = …" in the same method as where you instantiate your formatter?

Comment: @rdelmar No it is not in the same method. I did move that code to the method and it did start working as expected. I guess I'm going to have to rethink my subclass approach. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with subclassing. The way you show it, you're creating your formatter as a local variable, so it will be deallocated as soon as that method finishes. You need to create a property (or ivar) for your formatter.

Answer (score 0):

No need to define timezone & locale, It will automatically take from your system.
use the same code without declearing locale and timezone, I hope it will work for you...

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd"];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:self.datePicker.date];
```